# Portrait screen touch vertical rotation on Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't work

Tags: screen, ubuntu-20.04, touchscreen, portrait

I have an ubuntu 20.04 system, so if I change my screen to portrait  vertical, touch doesn't work well. It seems to be X and Y inverted.

Does anybody know what's happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution! You have to rotate the Calibration Matrix with udev rules.

Look for the touch screen here:

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices
```

And see which event is using. Then...

```
udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/input/event6 | grep name
```

This will return something like this:

```
ATTRS{name}=="Multi touch...."
```

Copy this line and:

```
sudo vim /etc/udev/rules.d/99-calibration.rules
```

Add this line there for left rotation screen:

```
ATTRS{name}=="Multi touch....", ENV{LIBINPUT_CALIBRATION_MATRIX}="0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000"
```

Instead, add this line there for right rotation screen:

```
ATTRS{name}=="Multi touch....", ENV{LIBINPUT_CALIBRATION_MATRIX}="0.000000 -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000"
```

Then, reboot your system, or if you prefer, restart services:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
sudo udevadm trigger
sudo service udev restart
```

By this way, you will have your touch screen working on vertical or portrait mode, and touch mode works.

After 98837458 tests, this is the only solution I found in order to change the landscape screen to portrait screen and make the touch works.

If you need a landscape screen again, you have to delete this file (99-calibration.rules) and reboot or restart services.

Wish this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Cris however depending on your device you may end up having to tweak the coordinates a bit.

I ended up using:

```
ATTRS{name}=="Multi touch....", ENV{LIBINPUT_CALIBRATION_MATRIX}="0.000000 -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000"
```

in the end :)

Comment: Yes!! It depends on screen rotation. In your case was right rotation so you need that coordinates

Answer (score 0):

generally rotation in 22 can be restored by re-installing
iio-sensor-proxy, youll notice when it is not working that systemctl outputs an errorin the end. By re-installing error disappears and rotation is restored.